# Write a batch file to download a .exe app from the internet

Tags: batch-file

I have to write a batch file to download a .exe application and I am finding it very difficult to make sense of the whole process.
All I have got done so far is;

```
start /d C:"\Program Files <x86>\Google\Chrome\Application" 
chrome.exe http://website/directory
```

This brings up the page I want to go to and the .exe file is on this page, but I don'y know how to download it, I tried;

```
start /d C:"\Program Files <x86>\Google\Chrome\Application" 
chrome.exe http://website/directory/download.exe
```

This was no good, it tried to load the page, while I thought it would just download the file.

If anyone can give me some insight into this, it would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use chrome. Depending on the tools you can rely on, use for example [`wget`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) or [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html). For documentation, have a look at the project's homepages ([wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/)), basic invokation is easy:

```
wget -o outfile http://example.com/url/to/file
curl -o outfile http://example.com/url/to/file
```

Comment: I have tried the curl method and I think it was successful, I got the following; % - 100, Total - 264, % - 100, Received - 264.... Judging from this I would say it is successful, but I cannot find the file anywhere on my server. I assumed it would have went to my default downloads folder, but it is not there and i cannot find it anywhere. Any ideas as to where it might be?

Comment: if you copy-pasted the code from above, it is named outfile and lies in the working folder. If you want another location, change `outfile` to some different path (for example `C:\outfile` or `%APPDATA%\outfile`).

Comment: I changed output to the location of my desktop and I get the following error message `Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Users/Daniel Dold/Desktop`

Comment: You use cygwin. In cygwin, file paths are notated differently than in regular windows. If you wish to use cygwin, use the suggested equivalent instead (`curl -o /cygdrive/c/Users/Daniel\ Dold/Desktop/myfilename http://example.com/url/to/file`).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change:

```
http://www.
```

to

```
ftp://ftp.
```

It would help if you provided the actual internet file link.